# React Native images not rendering on newer version of iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

I am running emulators to test a React Native application. One is an iPhone 6 running iOS 12.4, the other is an iPhone 11 running iOS 14. I am noticing that images are not being displayed on iOS 14, but are rendering correctly on Android and iOS 12.4. The elements containing images are rendering correctly and can be clicked/are still functional, but any images are just not displayed.

I am using React Native version 0.61.4

iPhone 6 (12.4)
[image: iPhone 6 (12.4)]

iPhone 11 (14)
[image: iPhone 11 (14)]

I went through with React Devtools and the inspected elements are below:

iPhone 6 Debugger
[image: iPhone 6 Debugger]

iPhone 11 Debugger
[image: iPhone 11 Debugger]

Is there any obvious reason for this? I have looked thoroughly through and just can't understand why the images are not rendering on iOS 14.

Comment: Please don't edit the title of your question to say it's solved. Accepting an answer (which you've done) is the right thing to do. See, e.g. [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/284827)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the arrival of iOS 14 some bugs arrived, in the versions previous to the current one of react-native this bug is occurring, the solution is to update your react-native version to 0.63.2>=, I did find this solution on this [facebook group](https://m.facebook.com/groups/476674372721669?view=permalink&id=1465723063816790)

Commit that fixed this on the current RN version: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428

Comment: Are there any applicable solutions that don't involve updating my version of React Native? I'm going to have a ton of bugs to fix with updating.

Comment: Try using this library, I haven't tried it but it seems to work, review the issues if don't work
https://github.com/huylvdev/react-native-fix-image

Comment: Don't worry, it's good that it was solved, try to change the title and add [RESOVED] Its possible that other people have the same problem :D

Comment: @IsraelAlfaro - Please don't suggest that people edit the title of questions to say it's solved. Accepting an answer (which has been done here) is the right thing to do. See, e.g. [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/284827)

Comment: I don't had idea, is good to know, Thanks for clearing this up for me :)